# footstep_planner model problem

Tags: ros, navigation, urdf, robot-model, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm new in ROS. I'm trying to start with footstep_planner. According **footstep_planner and Getting-Started tutorials** install all packages that we need. Then i'm running `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping` for Fixed Frame /map, `~/naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-linux32/naoqi --verbose --broker-ip 127.0.0.1` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/naoqi-sdk-1.14.5-linux32/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH NAO_IP=127.0.0.1 roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver_sim.launch` then `roslaunch nao_description nao_v4_publisher.launch` for viz NAO as **NAO Getting-Started**  tutorial say. After all this manipulation run `roslaunch footstep_planner footstep_planner_complete.launch`. And all run without problem. But when i'm adding robot model i see model made of cylinders, also i can't move this model out of corner. Also there is some problem with planner. When path already done map sometimes lose texture or exit with error. How can i get model like in footstep_planner video and how to move this model to the start point?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140951/footstep_planner-model-problem/) by [antongepard](https://answers.ros.org/users/13456/antongepard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you are mixing up a few things. If you are new to ROS, then best start with the beginners tutorials to get an understanding of the basic workings, frames and functionalities.

1. Do not run gmapping just the get a "map" frame, unless you really have a 2D laser running and an environment to map (real or Gazebo). You can use the fake_localization launch file in `footstep_planner` to directly map `/odom` to `/map` (i.e. open-loop navigation based on odometry.
2. You launch a simulated Nao and you launch a footstep planner, of course they are not connected in any way "magically"... for real navigation planning you need to use the `footstep_navigation` node instead, but be prepared to read the source code (there is no official documentation - use at your own risk). The footstep planner itself does not care about the actual robot, only about its stepping model.
3. The default Nao visualization is a simple cylinder model because the real mesh model currently cannot be distributed (yet) due to legal reasons. Ask Aldebaran Robotics for further explanations or read the current progress on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-aldebaran

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antongepard](https://answers.ros.org/users/13456/antongepard/) on 2014-03-28**:
Thank you very much) I'll get it.